# How to recursive Promises in a loop and passing argument to another

Tags: javascript, node.js, es6-promise, apple-musickit-js

I've checked other threads on SO but none really answers the questions as each answer ommiting something necessary for my case, and none of it is for Apple Music. Apple API is heavily promise-based and even `async/await` returns promise instead of response:(
I am trying to get all mine playlists, but Apple imposes offset limit of 25 so I have to do this in batches.
Currently I ended with something like this:

```
 async function getAllP() {
  let totalresult =[];
    window.music.api.music("/v1/me/library/playlists").then(function(o){
        let re = o.data;
        totalresult.push(re.data);
        if ("next" in re) {
          // what to insert here?
        } else {
          return totalresult;
        }
    });
 }
```

after many failed attempts to properly creates promises in loop or chaining them. I know I need some recursive function. if the keyword "next" is present in response data, then value of this key is url to fetch another batch of playlist so I need to pass that url to another promise.But I cannot set explicit .then chaining because I don't know how long that chain will be. In my case there is 80 playlists but other users may have different number so what I am struggling with is how to write loop/recursive internal function with proper argument passing to get `totalresult` at the end and without pyramid of doom
`totalresult` is an 'upper' variable designed to store all the responses objects.

Update:
for those who wanted how response data looks like (copied from console)

```
getAllPlaylist()
Promise { <state>: "fulfilled", <value>: undefined }

music.api.music('/v1/me/library/playlists')
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
​
<state>: "fulfilled"
​
<value>: Object { request: {…}, response: Response, data: {…} }
​​
data: Object { next: "/v1/me/library/playlists?offset=25", data: (25) […], meta: {…} }
​​​
data: Array(25) [ {…}, {…}, {…}, … ]
​​​
meta: Object { total: 80 }
​​​
next: "/v1/me/library/playlists?offset=25"
​​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​​
request: Object { baseUrl: "https://api.music.apple.com", path: "/v1/me/library/playlists", url: "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/playlists", … }
​​
response: Response { type: "cors", url: "https://api.music.apple.com/v1/me/library/playlists", redirected: false, … }
​​
<prototype>: Object { … }
​
<prototype>: Promise.prototype { … }

music.api.music('/v1/me/library/playlists?offset=25')
Promise { <state>: "pending" }
```

SOLUTION:

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will solve your issue,

```
const getAll = async () => {
  const totalResult = [];
  const getP = async (url) => {
    const { data } = await window.music.api.music(url);
    const hasMore = "next" in data;
    totalResult.push(...data);
    if (hasMore) return getP(data.next.url);
  };
  const url = "/v1/me/library/tracks";
  await getP(url);
  return totalResult;
};
```

Comment: @ikhvjs I'm sorry it was a mistake, I clicked edit on your answer.

Comment: I hade to modify this code as the returned object data has also 'data' property, so I am checking e.g. "next" in data.data. and url endpoint is playlists not 'tracks'.
However still when I run this in browser console I only get first 25 results. 
Thanks for the example tough, you shown me weird syntax I never used like dots notation  and that `const hasMore`

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot check if this works or not because Apple has some problems on its end and I got 'Method not allowed' and CORS problem

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure how the response data looks like.
I guess you are looking something like below:

Note: you may handle error yourself.

```js
async function getAllP() {
    const totalresult = [];
    let url = "/v1/me/library/playlists";
    while (true) {
        const o = await window.music.api.music(url);
        const re = o.data;
        totalresult.push(re.data);
        if ("next" in re) {
            url = re.next.url; // assume there is a url in the next.
            continue;
        }

        break;
    }

    return totalresult;
}
```

Comment: I added in question how the response look like :)

Comment: You can do `while(url)` and `url = re.next.url` without ifs and continues and breaks. *(btw. I thing it's just `url = re.next`)*

Comment: @Sebastian, anyway, I hope you get the idea of what I trying to do in the codes. How you handle the data is up to you.

Comment: @Thomas since when it's possible to write like that? isn't that confusing to read?

Comment: @Sebastian, good that it helps. Please accept the answer. It may help some future readers.

Comment: I accepted but I prefer Rahul modified solution because it gets me one array of results instead of arrays of arrays of result,but it's no big deal.

Comment: @Sebastian, it is fine. If you understand the idea of chaining Promise in async/await, that’s good enough. The handling of data is up to you because it is trivial to your question.

Answer (score 0):

> You can do `while(url)` and `url = re.next.url` without ifs and continues and breaks.

> @Thomas since when it's possible to write like that? isn't that confusing to read?

```js
async function getAllP() {
  const totalresult = [];

  let url = "/v1/me/library/playlists";
  while (url) {
    const { data } = await window.music.api.music(url);
    totalresult.push(...data.data);
    url = data.next;
  }

  return totalresult;
}
```

@Sebastian, is this confusing to read?

*While I have an url, do ...*

And the concept of [truthy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Truthy) and [falsy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Falsy) values exists since forever in JS.

Comment: (...data.data) is confusing.  and if you use `url = re.next.url` instead of `if (url = re.next.url)` then yes, it's confusing.
I learned that keywords are important in syntax. In Swift you can write closures in simplified syntax and it's difficult to read.